# How to avoid minor routing errors in ZF2

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

Is there a way to write routing scripts in ZF2 so that lone parameter escapes don’t lead to error messages?  In the Album module, for example, the routing is set up like this:

```
// …

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',

// …
```

In this scenario, the url `mydomain/album` will route to the index view, and the url `mydomain/album/index` will also route to the index view; but the url `mydomain/album/` will cause an error message.  In an effort to anticipate some of the ‘typos’ that users might make and treat them accordingly, is there a way to write routing scripts so that `mydomain/album/` works as well?  Also, is there a way to route all imperfect urls that are not matched by routing to a page that provides further instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the Album module, for example, the routing is set up like this

It *was* set up like that in earlier versions of the manual. It's now set up like this, which does exactly what you need.

```
'route'    => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
```

As you can see the trailing slash after `/album` is itself defined as an optional parameter `[/]` so it matches both `/album` and `/album/`

See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html#routing-and-controllers

As an aside, if you care about SEO, it's worth paying attention to [Google's recommendations on duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) if you go with this, since you now have 2 distinct urls matching the same content (3 if you include the optional `/index` action.)

Comment: Good point regarding SEO; although the route won't match `/album/create/` or any route with the trailing slash and no `id` parameter (not sure if that was the requirement or not)